# Add metadata to identify Docker Compose instances in a script

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a tool which manages a series of Docker Compose intances, all created from the same Compose File. I do not want to make too many assumptions about the compose file, because it is not part of the tool but of a different project. The tool should be able to identify the Compose project it has created and should be able to retrieve some metadata that was used when creating an project (e.g. environment variables passed to the Compose File), so that the projects can be listed, re-created, destroyed etc.

From what I understand, the only way to add metadata to Compose projects is through the Compose file, e.g. on a service with the `label` key. I see the following solutions to my problem, all of which seem like a hack or don't work in my situation:

- Add those labels to the original Compose file, but the original file shouldn't have to know anything about my tool.
- <erge a generated Compose file into the project (by passing `--file` multiple times to `docker compose`), but that would mean that I would probably have to add a dummy services just add those labels to, which feels quite ugly.
- Store the metadata in some file, but then I would have to handle the case where it gets out of sync, e.g. because of a failed operation or because someone delted/modified one of the project without using my tool.

Ideal would be something in the same style as what `docker container create --label <key>=<value>` provides, e.g.:

```bash
docker compose -f ... -p ... up --label <key>=<value>
```

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Compose already adds labels identifying the project and service.  The [Compose Specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#labels) documentation notes:

> Compose implementations MUST create containers with canonical labels:
>
> - `com.docker.compose.project` set on all resources created by Compose implementation to the user project name
> - `com.docker.compose.service` set on service containers with service name as defined in the Compose file

It's not noted in the earlier versions of the Compose file documentation, but I believe the Python `docker-compose` version 1.x tool created the same labels.

`docker inspect` a specific container I have running includes a number of other labels but they look less useful for identifying a project this way.  The one specific thing that may help you for this application is

```json
"com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/Users/dmaze/.../docker-compose.yml"
```

which appears to point to the Compose file.  That's "just" YAML so you may be able to parse that and match it up with what you see in the containers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly that doesn't give me back the environment variables I passed to `docker compose up`. All projects created using my tool use the same Compose file, parametrized using variables. They're multiple test instances of the same application running in parallel.